# How to update discontinued items from vendor in magento2

Tags: magento2, stock-status, manage-stock, stock-availability, dropshipping

we update stock from vendor, when a product is out of stock or discontinued, they are not getting update. the feed to qty=0 else just remove them from the feed and I cannot know which items they are and set them to out of stock or qty=0.
Any ideas how to deal with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the feed always contains all active products then everytime you import try to find all sku's that are not in the feed that have a quantity higher than 0 in magento and set their quantity to 0.

Otherwise you will need to work with your feed provider to give you something to be able to know which products are in stock or out of stock.

Comment: Thanks. What about checking items that were not updated in X time and set them to qty=0?

Comment: That could work unless you only receive products that have changed lets say in the last 24 hours and that a specific product stock did not change recently you might desactivate it while in reality it is still available.